# Important Blender shorcuts for object modeling

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, shortcut

A few years ago, I've learned basic modeling with Blender through a university course. However, now I need to use Blender again and it turns out I forgot all of the useful shortcuts that were indispensable to my work.

What are the most useful shortcuts when modeling objects in Blender?

Comment: the way you warded it "best shorts for modeling" is probably going to draw close votes as "primarily opinion-based." You might want to [edit] that, and change it a bit.

Comment: @David If I said "most commonly used shortcuts" instead of "most useful shortcuts", would that be enough? Most commonly used has an objective answer, though I doubt that data is open to the public.

Comment: meh, either way it's kind of the same thing. I think the question is ok. Was just trying to find a way to steer you clear of some DVs.

Comment: Blender has a LOT of keyboard shortcuts - and as others have mentioned, "the most useful shorrtcuts" will vary based on each person's workflow and preferences.

Answer (score 7):

**Important** short are obviously biased.

<kbd>G</kbd> - Grab
<kbd>R</kbd> - Rotate
<kbd>S</kbd> - Scale
<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> - Toggle Object/Edit Mode
<kbd>E</kbd> - Extrude
<kbd>F</kbd> - Make Face/Edge
<kbd>X</kbd> - Delete
<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> - Loop Cut
<kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> - Vertex / Edge Slide
<kbd>I</kbd> - Inset
<kbd>W</kbd> - Specials Menu
<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> - Vertex Menu
<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> - Vertex Menu
<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> - Vertex Menu
<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> - Switch Vertex/EdgeFace mode
<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> - Edge Loop select

<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>S</kbd> followed by <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> - Constrain the grab/rotate/scale action to a specific axis.
[The above] followed by <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> - Constrain the grab/rotate/scale action to a specific plane.

<kbd>Space</kbd>- Search for a command

#### Hotkey Maps by [mrdeyo](http://www.mrdeyo.com/blender-shortcuts/)

[image]

[image]

#### [Interactive Hotkey Map](http://waldobronchart.github.io/ShortcutMapper/#Blender)

Currently for 2.78, but there aren't many modeling changes.

#### How to find all hotkeys

In Blender, press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to open up the settings menu. Locate the **Input** rider and go to the **3d View** section. The operations and hotkey for modeling will be found under **Object Mode** and **Mesh**.

[image]

#### How to find a specific hotkey

Open up the menu and locate the desired operation, the hotkey is written to the right of it.

[image]

Comment: Another command that I've now learned that I find helpful is Space to launch command search.