# How to fix ugly lines in my mesh?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I would like my mesh to achieve similar shape (helmet) like this:

[image]

The mesh:

I know my mesh is far away from look like what I want, but I'm kinda newbie so I'm trying the best with what I got.

Without subsurf (just for let you know how it looks without it):

[image]

Base mesh with subsurf:

[image]

[image]

How can I get rid of those weird and ugly lines or achieve similar form?

Thank you for helping guys!, got something similar @Manu Järvinen , @Leander, @miceterminator

[image]

Comment: Im not good at modelling but I think you can use "Loop Cut and Slide" and delete the top most part and fill it instead

Comment: Hi. Please don't add unnecessary information to the title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT: haha, Leander beat me to it by 3 minutes with the same kind of answer :)

For the reference image type of helmet (a stretched sphere) I definitely would start with a cube that has Subsurf modifier applied:

[image]
[image]
[image]

After that, just add a new Subsurf modifier to it and it's smooth as silk and still quite easily editable:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Even at the risk of sounding demotivating: You can't subdivide a cylinder and call it modeling. I'd advise you to follow some basic modeling tutorials, *before* creating objects of your own.

Your cylinder contains an n-gon, a face with more than four vertices and four edges. Ngons don't work well with the subdivision surface modifier. Create the topology from quads (faces with four vertices). See [Manu](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118148/30849)'s answer for a possible workflow. I just started with the default cube and did the subdivision with the specials menu (<kbd>W</kbd>).

[image: possible helmet geometry]

[miceterminator](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118139/30849qqqqPaa)'s answer states to start with a halved sphere. While this may be a good starting point, a sphere intially has triangles, which produce non-smooth geometry with the subdivision modifier.

Here are things you want to do:

- Use fewer polygons on an intersecting loop. With more polygons, you have less control and positioning them becomes more time consuming.
- Place more polygons by hand.
- Setup reference images in your 3D view.
- Use the **mirror** and subdivision modifier.
- **Use only quads.**

Here are some [useful modeling commands](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/107408/308491q).

Comment: Thank you mate, your answer was all useful! , upvoted right now, it helped me a lot!

Comment: @Leander *"which are suited for subdivision as well"*...I don't think that is what you meant...

Comment: @JakeD Thanks, feel free to edit next time.

Answer (score 2):

I think that starting with a cylinder is a unfortunate choice.

I would suggest 3 different approaches:

1. Start with a sphere (ICO or UV) and use [proportional editing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/proportional_edit.html)

   1. Select the top/bottom most vertex
   2. Grab along z-axis while adjusting the falloff and size of the proprtional editing to your liking.
2. Start with a sphere (ICO or UV) and try scaling the vertices uniformly along the z-Axis
3. define the shape of your helmet with a line and the use the spin tool. This is described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35485/245) for a wine glass